# Web service not work in loob success

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I want to use web service to make more webmethod .But it go to loop error in javascript. What is wrong code in web service. If i make web medthod in codebehide my code is work fine. what's wrong when i want to check debug code in web service it can't debug my code in web service. it hard to say,but if u see my code i think u will understand more.

This is my code ajax in javascript

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "report.asmx/GetreportDoctor",
            data: "{}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
        //for get selected value from codebehide
        $('#<%= ddReport.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                $('#<%= hfSelectedValue.ClientID%>').val($('#<%= ddReport.ClientID%>').val());
            });        
    });
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        $('#<%= ddReport.ClientID%>').empty();
        var dt = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        var dropdown = $('#<%=ddReport.ClientID%>');
        var order = "";
        var test = dt.Table1[0][1];
        var num = dt.Table1.length;
        var optGroup;

    }
    function OnError() {
        alert("Failed!!!");
    }
```

And this is my webmethod code in web service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
// implementation
 public class report : System.Web.Services.WebService{
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetreportDoctor()
    {
        String daresult = null;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection EMR_Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.24.36;Initial Catalog=EMR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=bpk$1234");
        EMR_Conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd_select = new SqlCommand("select rowID, code, create_by FROM MED_main where type = 1 order by create_by", EMR_Conn);
        dr = cmd_select.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds);
        return daresult;
    }
    private static string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            }

            dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);
    }
  }
```

this is result when i run web service

This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.
Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.
How can i do when i create webmethod in codebehide is work fine but i can not add more webmedthod in code behide .if it can please tell .thank you so much.

Comment: Change your error function like this and you will get the exact error. function OnError(response) {
        alert(response);
    }

Comment: @MairajAhmad
Why it Unknow web method GetreportDoctor in web service.
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>Unknown web method GetreportDoctor."

Comment: it is not finding the webmethod try to change the url in ajax call.

Comment: Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script. why can u help me please.@MairajAhmad

Comment: I don't understand"why can u help me " and yes you have already given this attribute in your class [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61094/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-user3001046).